# MVC in iOS with custom UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiview, uiviewcontroller

How do you create custom UIView with its controls in iOS??

Lets say I want Radio Streamer just with Play/Pause buttons and scroller. Also lets say I'll create new model (singleton) for that streaming.

How do I handle View and controlling? Do I create UIView and add actions (IBOutlets) to that UIView, or I need ViewController also? Or should I then just use ViewController + model without UIView? Because I saw they always say model and view should never communicate so I dont think its good idea to have just UIView and actions in it...

I have created Model (singleton) and ViewController (.xib which is view 320x50 with Play/Pause and scroller). I have implemented model and actions inside controller and now when I want to use that controller (so radio streamer) I use this code:

```
RadioPlayerViewController *controller = [[RadioPlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RadioPlayerViewController" bundle:nil];
[controller.view setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), 300)];
[self addChildViewController:controller];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

Is that good aproach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

way you say and implement is  correct  you have make model class extend with NSObject class here you create named singleton class  that is fine with model class

now about view and controller in objective c this part is combine in objective c with Viewcontroller but if you want you can separated view form view controller class

what you did is perfectly fine if you need some controller with it relevant methods and need to sparted form main parent controller and need to serve as indiviual component that you can use this approch  here you create  RadioPlayerViewController.

you can also create custom view and than add this view in view controller

for how to create custom view you refer this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view

this is used when you need some reusable views that used in many screens.

way you implement is good approach for custom component you can make changes in component and easily modify it with out any trouble in parent controller.

Comment: Thanks on answer, saw that post on raywenderlich but in that tutorial its clear mixing model with view which is always said as bad thing...

Comment: yes you are right model with view are not proper way.but if i have that only display some content in labels and images than in that case i have create property of imageview and label in custom view and set them in parent controller with model object.so at that time  i just create custom view.but if i need create some controller that need to work separately with methods than you need to add view controller  way you did